# asmx won't invoke using https

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx

I am running a web service, and when run on my local machine works fine. However, when deployed into production I am having some issues. When I visit the site: https://[mydomain]/[mywebservice.asmx] I am given a list of web methods as expected (note: all web methods listed all correctly have https in their respective links). I click on one of them and I get my SOAP information along with the ability to test my web method - also as expected. When I enter a value and click Invoke, I get an error that page cannot be found - and the reason is because the Invoke sends me to the http version of my website. A quick view source on the asmx tells the story:

```
<form target="_blank" action='http://[mydomain]/[mywebservice.asmx]/[mywebmethod]' method="POST">
```

I need for this action to be https, but I cannot figure out how to get this changed. I've looked everywhere and cannot find this setting and have exhausted all of my resources. Any help is appreciated.

Server: Windows 2003 SP2

Comment: But your `action` attribute specifies `http`. Where would you _expect_ it to go?

Comment: Right, that's the problem. I need the action to be https. Somewhere there has to be a setting that tells the asmx what to use.

Comment: This is the default asmx test interface, right? Who cares if its https. Your service client will have to specify the correct https address anyway.

Comment: This is true, but we have support personnel that could benefit from using these web-service tests when troubleshooting or supporting customers.